# iOS (Obj-C) Saving User Specific Objects To Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

So I have an object class called "Nootropic" on Parse, and I'm trying to save a specific object from the "Nootropic" class to a user as "Favorite", the problem I've been running into is when a user clicks "favorite" the object will become a "favorite" for all users, not just that one user.

Would appreciate any help/recommendations

Comment: please, post your code

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup a `One-to-Many Relationships` between your `ParseUser` and the `Favorite`. Check this tutorial: https://parse.com/tutorials/one-to-many-relationships--2

Also as @neil suggest you should post some code.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get that user object using PFQuery. and then save favorite object in particular that user record.

For e.g. Store the favorite object in current login user then use this code.

```
PFUser * user = [PFUser currentUser];
PFObject *objfavorite = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"favorite"];
user[@"favorite"] = objfavorite;
[user saveInBackground];
```